# Schedule airflow jobs on bi-weekly basis

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I have gone through SO and web, observed this question asked previously however that question didn't answer. So asking the same question again.

**Previous Question Link:**

[Schedule airflow job bi-weekly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63565229/schedule-airflow-job-bi-weekly)

[How can I schedule bi-weekly jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435719/how-can-i-schedule-bi-weekly-jobs)

I have a requirement that I want to schedule an airflow job every alternate Friday. However, the problem is I am not able to figure out how to write a schedule for this. As I have 20 DAGS need to schedule on a bi-weekly basis, looking for a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The `schedule_interval` of a DAG supports cron expression and `datetime.timedelta`, it's stated in the [Airflow 1.10.1 docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.1/scheduler.html) - I would assume this is still valid even if not mentioned in the latest docs:

> schedule_interval is defined as a DAG arguments, and receives preferably a cron expression as a str, or a `datetime.timedelta` object.

So you should be able to set `schedule_interval=timedelta(weeks=2)`. The following actually works, tested it with Airflow 1.10.2:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

default_args = {
    'task_concurrency': 3,
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'wait_for_downstream': True,
    'retries': 0,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 9, 4),
}

SCHEDULE_INTERVAL = timedelta(weeks=2)
with DAG("bi-weekly-dag", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=SCHEDULE_INTERVAL, catchup=True) as dag:
    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='bash_test',
        bash_command='echo 1',
        dag=dag
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting Airflow 2.2.0 this is possible.

You can create a custom [Timetable](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/timetable.html#timetables) and [customize the DAG scheduling](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/timetable.html) accordingly.
If you are able to [define the scheduling logic](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/timetable.html#define-scheduling-logic) by implementing `next_dagrun_info` and `infer_manual_data_interval` then Airflow would simply use this logic to schedule the task.
An example can be found [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_modules/airflow/example_dags/plugins/workday.html).